# AlamofireObjectMapper crashes while converting JSON to object

Tags: ios, alamofire, objectmapper, alamofireobjectmapper

**User model :**

```
import Foundation
import ObjectMapper

class User: Mappable {

    // Variables
    var userInfo: UserInfo?
    var token: String?

    required init?(map: Map) {

    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        self.userInfo <- map["user_info"]
        self.token <- map["token"]
    }
}

class UserInfo: Mappable {

    // Variables
    var fullName: String?
    var firstName: String?
    var lastName: String?
    var email: String?
    var employeeCode: Int?

    required init?(map: Map) {

    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        self.fullName <- map["full_name"]
        self.firstName <- map["first_name"]
        self.lastName <- map["last_name"]
        self.email <- map["email_id"]
        self.employeeCode <- map["emp_code"]
    }
}
```

**Actual JSON :**

```
{
    "user_info": {
        "full_name": "test full name",
        "first_name": "test first name",
        "last_name": "test last name",
        "email_id": "a@b.com",
        "emp_code": 111
    },
    "token": "------"
}
```

**Alamofire request :**

```
AF.request("\(TimelyUrls.shared.kServerUrl)\(TimelyUrls.shared.kLoginUrl)", method: .post, parameters: requestDict, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: TimelyUrls.shared.HEADER).responseObject { (response: DataResponse<User>) in
            print(response.result)
}
```

Crash received on `responseObject` :

[image]

**Note** : The request works fine. When I try a simple Alamofire request, it works :

```
AF.request("\(TimelyUrls.shared.kServerUrl)\(TimelyUrls.shared.kLoginUrl)", method: .post, parameters: requestDict, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: TimelyUrls.shared.HEADER).responseJSON { (response) in
            print(response)
}
```

Comment: You force-unwrap queue, which defaults to nil.

Comment: @MartinM : I am not passing queue parameter. It is optional.

Comment: And thats the error then, that you are not passing it. The parameter defaults to nil as you can see in your image. And when you pass it to the response function, you force-unwrap it.

Comment: @MartinM : That is handled in the library. The parameter is optional. It is not mandatory to pass it.